# Is this the correct format to write this? It's not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm getting back to learning JavaScript and wondering why this isn't working. No errors are showing in the console.

I made it work with dry coding it but now I'm trying to not use dry and it's not working.

```
let simonLi = document.querySelector('#simon');
let simonPic = document.querySelector('#simon-pic');
let bruceLi = document.querySelector('#bruce');
let brucePic = document.querySelector('#bruce-pic');
let benLi = document.querySelector('#ben');
let benPic = document.querySelector('#ben-pic');


let pictureChange = pic => {
    if (pic.className === "hide") {
        pic.classList.remove("hide");
    } else {
        pic.classList.add("hide");
    }
};

simonLi.addEventListener('click', pictureChange(simonPic));

bruceLi.addEventListener('click', pictureChange(brucePic));

benLi.addEventListener('click', pictureChange(benPic));
```

No error messages and it's suppose to hide and show the image whenever the li is click.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please note that "It's not working" is an opinion, not an actual problem: the computer's doing exactly what you're telling it to do. Take the [tour], read [how to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) and then make sure to explain what you want to have happen, what you've written to make that happen, what it does instead, and what you've looked/search for in order to first try to solve the problem yourself. Ideally, for small pieces of code, provide a [mcve] so that people can reproduce your problem themselves based on your description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attaching the result of the function pictureChange (which happens to be `undefined`)to the click event, instead of attaching a function.

You can try replacing

```
let pictureChange = pic => {
    if (pic.classList.contains("hide")) {
        pic.classList.remove("hide");
    } else {
        pic.classList.add("hide");
    }
};
```

With

```
let pictureChange = pic => {
    return function() {
        if (pic.className === "hide") {
            pic.classList.remove("hide");
        } else {
            pic.classList.add("hide");
        }
    }
};
```

While your at it, consider using `pic.classList.toggle()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

This might work better:

```js
let simonLi = document.querySelector('#simon');
let simonPic = document.querySelector('#simon-pic');
let bruceLi = document.querySelector('#bruce');
let brucePic = document.querySelector('#bruce-pic');
let benLi = document.querySelector('#ben');
let benPic = document.querySelector('#ben-pic');

function pictureChange(pic) {
  pic.classList.toggle('hide')
}

simonLi.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  pictureChange(simonPic)
});

bruceLi.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  pictureChange(brucePic)
});

benLi.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  pictureChange(benPic)
});
```

```css
.hide {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="simon"><span id="simon-pic">Simon</span></div>
<br />
<div id="bruce"><span id="bruce-pic">Bruce</span></div>
<br />
<div id="ben"><span id="ben-pic">Ben</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This shortens your code sigificantly:

```js
for (const li of document.querySelectorAll('li')) {
  li.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    if (event.target.matches('li[id]')) {
       document.getElementById(`${event.target.id}-pic`).classList.toggle('hide');
    }
  })
}
```

This assumes **all** your `li` work the way you've shown. Otherwise, give all those `li` a common CSS class, e.g. `class="li-with-pic"` and adjust the `querySelector` accordingly:

```js
for (const li of document.querySelectorAll('.li-with-pic')) {
  li.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    if (event.target.matches('.li-with-pic')) {
       document.getElementById(`${event.target.id}-pic`).classList.toggle('hide');
    }
  })
}
```